# Returning request payload in case of error

Tags: java, rest

Is returning request body along with error code(response) in case of invalid payload a standard practice ?

**Request**:

```
{ "payload" : " + request" }
```

in the above json "+" is not accepted character in my API, and server is returning an error message representing that request payload consists of invalid characters.

**Response** :

```
{"payload": " + request", "error":"Invalid character '+' in request payload"}
```

Above is the response being returned.

Note: Agreed it is inefficient to send request payload to and from, which is originated from the client.

Comment: I'd say it depends but so far I've rarely seen the request payload being sent back. If you feel that in your particular case sending back the request payload (which the client should know already) would help and not impose any performance issues (in case of huge payloads) or security considerations (not sure what those could be but better safe than sorry :) ) then I'd say "why not"?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your inputs. True that sending back the request payload might add to performance overhead, how would it compromise on security?

Comment: Well, that's why I wrote that I'm not sure what security implications there could be because I don't have the time to thoroughly think it through but the more data you send over the network (and in different directions) the more vectors for data leaks there are. The problem with security is that hackers normally think of ways to attack a system before we do in order to prevent them so the only thing we can do is prevent those that are known and reduce possibilities for new ones :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is returning request body along with error code(response) in case of invalid payload a standard practice ?

Somewhat - think about the forms that you see on the web; what happens when you submit a form, but the server thinks one or more of your values is invalid?  Typically, you get a new representation of the form, with the problem fields highlighted.

It might be possible to build that kind of signal directly into a media type, but I don't think I could point you at a standard for doing that.

With [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), you've got some freedom with extension members that you could use to echo back the original data.